# Leaflet label plugin on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have been developing a map using leaflet along with leaflet label plugin.
The plugin is working fine but on mobile devices it is not destroying the previous      popup when another polygon touched.
You can check a demo here :
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.label/
It would be very kind if anyone could help me to solve the problem with touch or find any other popup plugin with hover works in touch devices also.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add the code where you think the error is in your post instead of making someone parse through your entire codebase on github.

Comment: Sorry maybe you have missed my point. The problem is not with my code. I am using a plugin which is working fine other than touch devices.So i m asking if someone has experienced the same problem and found a solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but isn't the solution here to contact the creator of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

dwkns opened [an issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/issues/114) in the Leaflet.label repository on GitHub. They also proffered an untested response which involved modifying the library. The plugin author hasn't yet replied.

One possible solution is to use [L.Browser.touch](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#browser) to test for touch device support, and then bind a Leaflet popup for touch browsers and labels for non-touch browsers. Good luck!